# What kind of cloud is this?

Tags: meteorology, clouds

I would like to know if anybody knows the name of this cloud formation.

The picture was taken in Bern Switzerland, just before a cold front moved in. I am thinking about roll clouds or Asperatus undulatus... It was wavy but the clouds formed rolls.

[image: cloud rolling over Bern]

Answer (score 1):

I think it is stratocumulus. Sometimes it rolls like that. Nice picture

Comment: would you please clarify how you ID'd this? I looked at http://www.clouds-online.com/cloud_atlas/stratocumulus/stratocumulus.htm and see Stratocumulus undulatus looks like these clouds, but I wonder how you tell it would help clarify the answer if you shared how you tell these apart from the OP's idea Asperatus undulatus.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Agata that it is stratocumulus.

This link talks about cloud types

[NWS JetStream](http://oceanservice.noaa.gov/education/yos/resource/JetStream/synoptic/clouds_max.htm)